# Multiple fullstops in regex for RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use the following rule to redirect pretty urls from `http://hostname.co.za/geoip/123.12.123.34` to `http://hostname.co.za/geoip/index.py?ip=123.12.123.34`

*.htaccess in /geoip*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*\..*\..*\..*)$ /geoip/index.py?ip=$1
```

This works fine to match only ip's, but when I try this, it gives a 500 server error:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*\..*)$ /geoip/index.py?ip=$1
```

I want to match not only ip's, but hostnames with at least one fullstop as well.
I have no idea why this shouldn't work...

Comment: Could you look for the probable error message explaining the 500 error in apache error log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the second pattern is that it also matches `index.py` and thus yields an infinite recursion. You can exclude that by using a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.py
RewriteRule ^(.*\..*)$ /geoip/index.py?ip=$1
```

Furthermore, you should use a more specific pattern than `.*` like `[^/.]+`, so:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.py
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.[^/.]+)$ /geoip/index.py?ip=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.[^/.]+\.[^/.]+\.[^/.]+)$ /geoip/index.py?ip=$1
```

Comment: Thanks, the index.py was the problem - sorted with the RewriteCond rule.

Comment: @bluegray: To show your appreciation, please accept Gumbo's answer (click the checkmark next to it).